# How to Build a realtime multiplayer game using action script (flash) and php backend

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, flash, multiplayer

I wanted to build a real time multi player game using flash (action script 3) as front end and use php as back end language and mysql database. There are lot of posts and tutorials online, but nowhere I found an article which would suffice my requirement.

I thought of using smartfox server. But lately they are not supporting php backend technology. Here is the answer by their technical person.

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=15791

This seemed to be a useful post, but it didn't give me complete information as to handle the game play with php back end.

http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/

Do we have to use web sockets in front end. And how to handle the user's delay on the website. Also I am supposed to use Facebook Login to get more users on the game.

My game should have multiplayer feature just like this one on facebook.
https://apps.facebook.com/livepool/

Can someone suggest me on this please.

Comment: Start with a client-server tutorial, I'd say. If you would be able to make that work, it will net you the information you seek.

Comment: thanks @Vesper. I have looked into some client-server architecture tutorials for multi player games. But I need a high level design detail which includes details regarding server I need to use? Whether php is really suitable or not? Do I have shift to node.js,erlang or some other technology? etc..

Comment: Well, PHP is suitable to a degree, as you can use PHP to form your dataset to be sent back and forth from client to server and back, and you can use PHP to interact with the server database that is bound to exist. It then comes to fine tune the request/response code both server-based and client-based to resolve collisions, handle network latency and occasional packet drop/loss of connection, handle numerous database requests and transactions, etc. In short, one can use PHP to make such a game.